# Using unigrams with phrasefields in SOLR

Tags: java, search, solr, lucene, edismax

I'm using solr to search documents and matching on one field and then want to boost based on keywords appearing in other fields.

Ex.

```
<str name="qf">
  name^1
</str>
<str name="pf">
   keywords1^2
   keywords2^1.2
   description^0.2
 </str>
```

So if I search for

```
q=foo+bar
```

and I have a result

```
name = "This is a foo bar"
keywords1 = "bar"
keywords2 = "foo cats dogs chicken"
description = "There is a foo in here with a bar"
```

The query gets a boost from description but not from keywords1 and keywords2. I know this is because pf searches keywords1 for "foo bar" (with phrase slop), not "foo" "bar". I would like to boost based on individual words. Is this possible without a plugin?

Things I have thought of:

I am aware of options like pf2 and pf3 but basically what I'm looking for is a pf1. I want to be able to boost on single words.

The reason I do not just add keywords1, keywords2 to qf is I do not want them to be matched. As keywords two has some terms that may not have anything to do with the document.

I could at query time break up the query and use bq

```
bq = keywords1:foo OR keywords1:bar etc...
```

but I would like to assign different weights to different fields, and that is cumbersome to build the query.

In summary I would like a parameter a la pf1.

Answer (score 1):

I looked through the SOLR source code and it was fairly straight forward to add a pf1 parameter to the edismax query parser - pf2 and pf3 use more general functions that can be called for pf1. However I really didn't want to have to recompile solr from source. I've managed a work around using nested queries.

I now have

```
<str name="qf">
  name^1
  keywords1^2
  keywords2^1.2
  description^0.2
</str>
```

And my query now looks like

```
q=(foo bar) AND _query_:"{!edismax qf='name'}foo bar"
```

So I get all the boosting of the first query but I restrict on name.